# How to fetch Individual output of different match_phrase inside one request

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I am able to run below query which is giving response as `total` of two `match_phrase`.

Inserting dummy data as below.

```
POST /mod1/_bulk
{ "index" : { } }
{ "msg": "BA1" }
{ "index" : { } }
{ "msg": "BA2" }
{ "index" : { } }
{ "msg": "BA2" }
{ "index" : { } }
{ "msg": "BA1" }
{ "index" : { } }
{ "msg": "BA2" }
{ "index" : { } }
{ "msg": "BA1" }
{ "index" : { } }
{ "msg": "BA1" }
{ "index" : { } }
```

`Request` -

```
GET mod1/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
    "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "msg": "BA1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "msg": "BA2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`Response` -

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 7,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Getting response as `7`, because `BA1` is `4` and `BA2` is `3`, so it is giving sum of two `match_phrase`, How can I get response as below i.e individual output of two `match_phrase`?

```
.
.
"BA1"
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,

.
.
"BA2"
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
```

Thanks,

Comment: only way currently i know is to run individual request with each 'match_phrase', but there are many 'match_phrase' to match and i do not want to create multiple requests and instead looking to create single curl request which will have multiple 'match_phrase'.

Comment: It won't always be a sum since a document can match few queries at once. Unless it's really a `keyword` field; then a simple `terms` aggregation would do.